# whenever i acces data from network using retrofit it works fine but in 2nd time can't find data through network using retrofit

Tags: java, android, wordpress, retrofit

I am trying to access data from the network (data is in the form of gson and i am using WordPress rest API) using retrofit but can't access. it shows me an error like data is null looks like retrofit can't find data but everything is good... looks like code is good and i don't know how to solve this. please help me I am a new developer.. it takes my 3 days

whenever i call getRetrofit() method it works fine... but when i call getImageRetrofit() then looks like this method won't work...this method return null value as shown in the logcat : 
ImageInfo: info: null

```
   private void getRetrofit() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
    Call<List<WPPost>> call = service.getPostInfo();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
            Log.e("Latest","response: "+response.body());
            for (int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++)
            {
                Log.e("main ","title "+response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " " +
                        response.body().get(i).getId() );
                String tempDate = response.body().get(i).getDate();
                tempDate = tempDate.replace("T"," ");

                String tempImageHref = response.body().get(i).getLinks().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getHref();
                Log.e("Href", "onResponse: "+tempImageHref);
                String link = response.body().get(i).getLink();
                Log.e("PostLink",link);

                getImageRetrofit(tempImageHref);


                list.add(new LatestModel(
                        response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                        tempDate,
                        tempImageHref,
                        LatestModel.IMAGE_TYPE,
                        response.body().get(i).getLink()
                        )
                );
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}



private void getImageRetrofit(String ImageHref) {
    Log.e("getImageRetrofit","called "+ImageHref);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
    Call<List<WPPostImage>> callImage = service.getImageInfo(ImageHref);
    callImage.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPostImage>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPostImage>> call, Response<List<WPPostImage>> response) {

            Log.e("ImageInfo","info: "+response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPostImage>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Link Failed: ",": t.printStackTrace()" );
        }
    });


}
```

here is my RetrofitArrayApi Interface.:

```
public interface RetrofitArrayApi {
@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=4")
Call<List<WPPost>> getPostInfo();

@GET("{id}")
Call<List<WPPostImage>> getImageInfo(@Path("id") String ImageHref);     }
```

Comment: What does return from backend when you access the `getImageInfo` api from a browser or postman etc.?

Comment: this link is stored: in temImageHref:  https://mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1780

Comment: in logcat it display like that: E/ImageInfo: info: null...also i double check my pojo model this is also correct

Comment: this is my baseurl: private String baseUrl = "https://mubashirsaddique.com/";

Comment: If `temImageHref` equals **mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1780**, `service.getImageInfo(ImageHref)` makes a request to baseurl + `temImageHref` = **mubashirsaddique.com/mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1780**

Answer (score 0):

You said at comments that `temImageHref: mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1780` and also your base url is `baseUrl = "mubashirsaddique.com"`. So you send a request to this address **mubashirsaddique.com/mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1780** when call `getImageInfo`.

Change your `getPostInfo` service. It should return just id(**1780** in your case) as href value and modify `RetrofitArrayApi`.

```
@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/media/{id}")
Call<List<WPPostImage>> getImageInfo(@Path("id") String ImageHref);
```

Comment: i used this way.
   ImageHref = ImageHref.replace("https://mubashirsaddique.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/","");
        Log.e("newImageHref",ImageHref);

Comment: @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/media/{id}")

    Call<List<WPPostImage>> getImageInfo(@Path("id") String ImageHref);

Comment: logcat:                   E/newImageHref: 1780

Comment: error:                  E/Link Failed:: : t.printStackTrace()

Comment: Can you change `onFailure` like this: `Log.e("Link Failed: ", t.getMessage()); t.printStackTrace();`

Comment: looks like it skip this method onResponse() and goes to onFailure() do you have any other option????????????????????

Comment: sorry, my bad. 
in logcat:    E/Link Failed:: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: It means the response has come but its format is wrong. You define it as json array `Response<List<WPPostImage>>` but a json object is coming

Comment: oooooooooooooooo thanks man..... you are too good... you are amazing...  how can I so much stupid...... I just removed <List and code works fine like a charm.... one again thanks man.... love from pakistan

Comment: :) happy for you. Maybe you can mark my answer as right asnwer :)

Comment: i do but it says: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.